# How to access IP camera using OpenCV in Android?

Tags: android, opencv, camera, rtsp

I am trying to get into OpenCV on android devices.I have been working with the samples in the OpenCV.

In the **Face detection sample** application I am able to get the frames from the phone's camera.But I need to access the RTSP feed from an IP camera.

In windows I could access the IP camera using **VideoCapture** class and the following works fine.

```
    cv::VideoCapture videoCapture;
    cv::Mat image;
    char* rtspURL = "rtsp://192.168.1.101/img/video.mpeg";

    if(!videoCapture.open(rtspURL))
    {
      cout<<"Can't connect to the camera!!"<<endl;
      return -1;
    }
```

But in Android I couldn't find a constructor for **VideoCapture** that accepts the camera url as an argument.It supports only the following.

```
    VideoCapture mVideoCapture1 = new VideoCapture();
    mVideoCapture1= new VideoCapture(2);
    //mVideoCapture1 = new VideoCapture(rtspURL); // doesn't work
    //mVideoCapture1.open(rtspURL); // doesn't work
```

How to access the IP camera using OpenCV in Android?

Comment: it's probably not supported  on android, since it would rely on the (missing) ffmpeg backend

Comment: @berak Is there any other way to access the RTSP stream using OpenCV for android?

Comment: not that i'd know, sorry. ( but again, i'm no expert on this. i just tried , what you did, before, and above was the answer.. )